# iPhone api's for locking screen and more

Tags: ios, iphone

I am brand new to developing for the iPhone.  It's looking like I need to create a app for my kids iPhones.  If you are familiar with MMGuardian, that's what I am after.  I want to create an application which based on trigger times will display a lock screen and not allow my children access during that time frame.  I can't seem to find anything like that on the market, so I figured I might take a stab at writing one myself.  My intent is to lock the phone during school hours.  I can't take it away, as they need it for after school in case I am running late or they have an issue or anything like that.

That being said, are there api's that I can leverage to create a global application which will provide (or reuse) a lock screen.  Further, MMGuardian has a nice lock & unlock feature based off of SMS text messages.

Any and all guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Apple API's dont usually give users controls like that.

Comment: Looks like me asking a question on how to do something is frowned upon. Not sure why, StackOverflow has been invaluable in helping me in the past either by responding to my questions but more so by searching for answers and finding other users with similar questions.   My guess is there may be someone else out there with similar questions.  Anyway, my apologies for offending Wain, Abizern, Bass Jobsen, mhwombat, and Abbas certainly that was not my intent.  To those who actually offered some feedback, thank you very much!  While the answer isn't what I wanted to hear, I am extremely gratefull!

Comment: Android fully opens their API for just about any task. Apple wants to protect its users from any Malware. To them its no justification to be able to lockout an iPhone. Imagine devevloping this... one bad move and you lock out your iPhone. Even if that wasnt the case functions that are built in to iOS are usually prohibited. As to why the question was closed. I am guessing its because its a "will Apple let me" question which cant be answered objectively.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the iOS SDK. Consider using parental controls in iPhone settings.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I did look into those, but unless I missed something obvious those controls will not meet my needs.  But thank you once more!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is Mobile Device Management, or MDM. Search Google for iOS MDM, and you'll find more information about it. I don't think there are any solutions out there right now that are geared towards parental control, it's more for corporations managing their devices in use by employees. But I think that ones geared toward parents are being worked on, which would allow you to remotely manage and monitor different aspects of the phone.

The iOS SDK doesn't contain anything that would allow you to implement something like this on your own.